# Secured JMS queue connection jboss

Tags: java, jboss, jms

I could create a secured JMS queue (JBoss server) connection using the following:

```
Connection connection = factory.createConnection(user, pw);
```

Is there a way to do the same when following is used:

```
public class Sender{
  @Inject
  private JMSContext context;

  @Resource(mappedName="java:global/jms/exampleQueue")
  private Queue queue;

  public void put(String message) {
            context.createProducer().send(queue, message);
    }
  }
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`JMSPasswordCredential` annotation](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/jms/JMSPasswordCredential.html).  For example:

```
@Inject
@JMSPasswordCredential(userName="guest",password="guest")
private JMSContext context;
```